# Unity Photon Network CustomPropeties not updating after loading new scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

I'm working on an online multiplayer game on Unity using Photon PUN and I'm having problems with the room CustomProperties.

In the original lobby screen, when I change the room properties it updates for all players, but when I start the game, loading a new level, I want to use CustomProperties so the MasterClient can set the same start time for all players. I'm setting/getting the custom properties from a Game Settings class attached to a DoNotDestroyOnLoad GameObject and the following getter/setter:

```
private static T GetProperty<T>(string key, T deafult)
{
    if (PhotonNetwork.CurrentRoom.CustomProperties.TryGetValue(key, out object value))
    {
        return (T)value;
    }
    else return deafult;
}

private static void SetProperty(string key, object value)
{
    ExitGames.Client.Photon.Hashtable table = PhotonNetwork.CurrentRoom.CustomProperties;
    if (table.ContainsKey(key))
    {
        table[key] = value;
    }
    else
    {
        table.Add(key, value);
    }
}
```

When I load the new scene, the previous CustomProperties remain unchanged, and new changes appear locally but do not appear for other players. I have tried using OnRoomPropertiesUpdate() but it doesn't activate after loading the new scene. Is there maybe something else that needs to be attached to a DoNotDestroyOnLoad object?

Answer (score 0):

After changing the table you have to re-assign it via [`SetCustomProperties`](https://doc-api.photonengine.com/en/pun/v2/class_photon_1_1_realtime_1_1_room.html#a3fb1bbb640e96bdaa4f24a65e276edbb) otherwise you are just changing the local copy.

```
private static void SetProperty(string key, object value)
{
    ExitGames.Client.Photon.Hashtable table = PhotonNetwork.CurrentRoom.CustomProperties;
    
    // No need to check Contains
    // This will either Add a new key or overwrite an existing one
    // -> This is more efficient and already behaves exactly the same ;)
    table[key] = value;

    PhotonNetwork.CurrentRoom.SetCustomProperties(table);
}
```

Comment: Ah, thank you so much! It appears I'm an idiot and accidentally deleted that line a few commits ago when I was testing something else. Thanks for the hashtable trick too!